# Resource (e.g. FLS index) exhaustion with CRT-statically-linked COM InProc servers

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, com, crt

I think **static-linking** (to CRT, i.e. `/MT` compiler option) is very *convenient* when building small tools, thanks to *easy deployment*. ([Sysinternals tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx) like Process Explorer are an example of that.)

However, someone made me note that the CRT uses several resources that might run out in contexts like *plugin architectures* (e.g. shell extensions): in particular, the [FLS index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to be the one that runs out quickest, and `LoadLibrary()` could fail when loading the 127th CRT-statically-linked DLL.

I've built some shell extensions, and I've never encountered this problem, though.

Has anyone ever experienced this *resource exhaustion* problem with CRT-statically-linked in-proc COM servers (like shell extensions)?

If so, is there a "fix" for that (other than using dynamic-linking to CRT, which unfortunately complicates deployment, and requires some megabytes download for VCRedist, when instead small stuff with CRT statically-linked is just a few hundreds kilobytes...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmya, this is a bit like worrying if you have a good backup in case a meteor impact destroys the machine.  The user of your shell extension would have figured out a while ago that something is a-miss.  Getting 100+ DLLs injected into a process every time he uses the File + Open dialog does not go unobserved, that program is dead to the world for a good 5 seconds or more.

So either he does something about it and cleans up his machine with a utility like SysInternals' AutoRuns.  You'll survive that if your extension is useful enough.  Or the user takes no countermeasure and is happy that there's a hard upper limit.  Your extension will fail but there's no way for the user to tell why.  You *might* get a support call, you know what to do about it.